# How to get value from inner function when using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, closures, protractor, karma-jasmine, end-to-end

I am trying to return the index value of a button that is part of a collection of buttons. i have spent a lot of time reviewing closures, but since this is protractor some of the information just does not seem to line up. Here is where I am so far:

I collect a list of buttons in to arrayElement - [button1, button2, button3].
I have a target element ... i.e. button2

If the button that I am looking for matches my target element, I want the index.

Here is what is my code:

```
var targetComponent = 'buttons2';
var buttonIndex;
var components;

browser.actions().mouseMove(homePage.componentIcon).perform();
components= homePage.gatherComponents();
buttonIndex = getIndex();

function getIndex () {
                components.each(function (component, compIndex) {
                    component.getText().then(function (name) {
                        if (name === targetComponent) {
                            return compIndex;
                        }
                    });
                });
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually need an index and not the actual button matching the text?

Comment: Alec each of my target button will have submenu items. When I click the target button, I need to collect sub menu Items. The next button from my target button is coming up as a submenu item member also. Script should:
1. Get all buttons and click target
//submenu items are now showing
2. Collect all Sub menu items
//here is where the index comes it. It allows me to go one button OVER from my target button and use that button as the end of the processing flag
3. Perform a function on all submenu items until you reach the button 1 over from target button (determined by targetButton.index + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually need an index, you can solve it with [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
function getIndex () {
    return components.map(function (component, compIndex) {
        return {
            text: component.getText(),
            index: compIndex
        };
    }).then(function (results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            if (results[i].text === targetComponent) {
                return results[i].index;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But, if you need to filter out an actual button by text, it's a good use case for [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
function getButton(targetComponent) {
    return components.filter(function (component) {
        return component.getText().then(function (text) {
            return targetComponent === text;
        });
    }).first();
}
```

Comment: Hi Alec:
Thanks for the responses. I found the top version to work for me but only if I resolve the value using "expect". If I actually need to value so that I can use it in a calculation (i.e. iterate from the index to another index), then how would I do that? Seems like it always comes back undefined. Thanks!

Comment: Alec:

So I went back over my notes on Promises and resolving them and I realized that I wasn't really that clear as i thought. So, I found that I needed to RESOLVE THE PROMISE with a .then(). Once I placed that in the chain of control ( i think that is what it is called) then the value was calculated. Many thanks to you. I appreciate the follow up and the clarity on the answers you always give! Peace!!